# Как получить адреса с определенного города SuggestView Yandex API?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Не могу понять как получить адреса вводимые пользователем с конкретного города. Т.е. если вводить сейчас, адреса показываются со всех городов, а мне нужно только адреса определенного города. Спасибо за помощь!

```
<input type="text" id="suggest"/>

<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;load=SuggestView&amp;onload=onLoad"></script>
<script>
function onLoad (ymaps) {
    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно смотреть в сторону "провайдера"

```
provider: {

            suggest:(function(request, options){

               return  ymaps.suggest(document.getElementById('city').value +", " + request);

                  })}

    });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQpGdL

Отдельно задать город (php || js)
только не сработает если указать город, в основном адресе. открыть инпут с городом, и поставить чекбокс, учитывать город или нет

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать определённый квадрат координат чтобы ограничить область поиска. Для этого есть опция `boundedBy`.  Координаты границ нужного города можно просмотреть на самих картах Яндекса. Квадрат - левый нижний угол - правый верхний угол(вроде).

```
function onLoad (ymaps) {
    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest', {
        boundedBy: [[30, 40], [50, 50]]
    });
}
```

Comment: а если задать `strictsBounds: true`, то он ведь некорректно поиск делает. Например, задаем `boundedBy: [55.42939357021221,86.88964843749997]` - это границы Казахстана, затем вводим название и поиск не находит по стране объект, что я делаю не так?